# loop through accounts and update

Tags: apex, account, list, field-update

I am currently updating contact related records on accounts which updates my contacts correctly. When i try this for account I get the error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: `void addAll(Account)`
>   from the type List.

What is wrong with my signature. See below.

```
public PageReference updateContacts() {
system.debug('accList '+accList);

contactList = new List<Contact>();
for(Account accnt :accList){
    contactList.addAll(accnt.Contacts);
}

accountList = new List<account>();
for(Account accntnew :accList){
    accountList.addAll(accntnew);
}
update contactList;
update accList;
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop to copy all the Accounts in the list, you can just use:

```
accountList = new List<account>();
accountList.addAll(accList);
```

or:

```
accountList = new List<account>(accList);
```

or:

```
accountList = accList.clone();
```

or not copy the list at all and just update using the original list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem exists in below line of code

```
accountList.addAll(accntnew);
```

`addAll()` function expects **list** or **set** in the [signature](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm), while you are giving it a single Account object.

You should be using `add()` instead.

Comment: You didn't mention complete requirements in the question, since your question was only related to the problem / Error, that's why you got that suggested answer. Please post another question with complete requirements, where the reader would know about `accList` and other variables in place.

Comment: This does not update the accountslist!?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: with your solution the accounts do not get updated